# Does C's rand() have to be random?

Tags: c, random

I was trying to get some info on the specification and implementation of `rand()` in C, and I can't find much information. As a matter of fact, I can't find anything apart from:

- rand() does not advance between function calls
- same seed always results in same numbers
- the random numbers are between 0 and `RAND_MAX`

Notably, *none of these things require randomness.* Specifically, I don't see anything that prohibits this implementation:

```
int randval = 0;

void srand(unsigned int seed) {
    randval = seed;
    return;
}

int rand() {
    return randval++;
}
```

This seems somewhat unrandom. Is there a bit of standard I'm missing?

(Also, is is bad to seed rand() with time(), then seed ISAAC with rand()?)

Comment: What's _random_? I mean, everything is random, the sequence `5555555555` is totally random, as well as the number `6`.

Comment: It doesn't have to be very random.  The standard includes a minimal acceptable implementation, which is not very random.  Don't forget [Dilbert's encounter with randomness](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: `rand()` is supposed to be only a very weak form of pseudo-random. It's nowhere near guaranteed to be random. If you actually need a real random, you'd need to implement it yourself, too.

Comment: I get that "random is a fuzzy concept". However, can we agree that when we can easily predict the next number after a few calls, that the function isn't very random? I tend to make games, and it's noticeable when every single obstacle is on the left. So, there's *something* to this randomness idea.

Comment: @Orion The standard way to make `rand` "more random" in non-critical applications is to call `srand` before the first usage. For example, the notorious `srand(time(NULL));` can do the job in your game.

Comment: You should avoid C `rand`, since you cannot know how it's implemented. For games, you may want to implement something like [xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift).

Comment: Note that C++11 introduced [new framework](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomBitGenerator) that provides decent quality pseudo-randomness, and also true randomness if available in the system. If you can use C++, of course.

Comment: "random" in programming means "predictable, repeatable and probably badly distributed". And your implementation is better than some standard libraries because you at least have the chance to generate all possible numbers.

Comment: "bad to seed rand() with time()"  --> Yes, if 2 instances of the program may execute at the same time.  Consider `time() ^ pid()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While notes in the C standard are not normative, it does say this:

[7.22.2.1 The rand function / note 295](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note295)

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with particular requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufficient for their needs.

So you are correct that a completely lazy implementation of the standard library can look like this. It's not bad to seed rand with `time`, it's as good as any other seed, and provides a certain degree of randomness so long as it's only seeded once. But I won't use `rand` for any serious application, precisely due to the lack of guarantees.

Comment: And please if you're using it for something like encryption key generation use an actual proven pseudorandom algorhitm for those.

Comment: @Magisch, if you are using it for something like encryption key generation, please use **actual randomness**. Pseudo-random are unsuitable for any and all cryptography applications.

Comment: @JanHudec Even the most sophisticated cryptographic KDFs are still pseudorandom, no? I always thought real random isn't a thing with computers

Comment: @Magisch, operating systems do provide sources of true entropy. Modern computers often have a dedicated source of that using a thermal noise to generate it, because SSL consumes a _lot_ of it. In absence of that, operating systems collect entropy from fine timing of external events like key presses, mouse movement or arrival of network packets. And since older windows didn't do even that, some key generators popped up a windows and asked you to move a mouse over it for a while to collect some true entropy.

Comment: @Magisch, KDFs are indeed pseudo-random, but the derivation relies on the password itself being randomly chosen and the entropy of the password is all entropy the encryption can count on—i.e. breaking the cipher is only as difficult as guessing the password. Since `rand` is not a KDF, it is mostly irrelevant for the discussion.

Comment: @Magisch, note that there is a difference between key *derivation* —
 where the randomness comes from the password — and key *generation* — where you must have source of entropy.

Answer (score 2):

Not only it does not have to be random, it **must not be random**, because it must be completely deterministic:

[§7.22.2.2/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.2.2p2):

> The srand function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to rand. If srand is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated. If rand is called before any calls to srand have been made, the same sequence shall be generated as when srand is first called with a seed value of 1.

If you need **true randomness**—for any cryptographic purposes you do—use `/dev/random` on Linux (and most other unices) and [CryptGenRandom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379942.aspx) on Windows.

If you are instead interested in how well the **pseudo-random** sequence resembles a random one, that is how much it is [statistically random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness), see [@Story Teller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43199573/201725).

Answer (score 0):

It has not to be random but pseudo-random (reproducible and deterministic) as stated in POSIX:

> The rand() function shall compute a sequence of pseudo-random integers
>   in the range [0, {RAND_MAX}]

This specification says that it is aligned with ISO-C standard.

Your proposition of implementation does not provide a pseudo-random sequence, obviously. A quick definition of pseudo-random generator could be: "a generator that provides uniform distribution", which yours are clearly not providing such. Your values are too trivially correlated to each others.